# Using Max function with datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a database full of machine orders. When the machine orders get changed the revision level changes, going from `0,1,2,......`.

The `MySql` statement that I have fellows:

```
"SELECT reference as ""Reference"", serial_number as ""Serial Number"", revision as ""Revision"", Model as ""Model"" FROM `configurator`.`final_order` WHERE shipped = '0' GROUP by serial_number"
```

I've also tried:

```
"SELECT reference as ""Reference"", serial_number as ""Serial Number"", MAX(revision) as ""Revision"", Model as ""Model"" FROM `configurator`.`final_order` WHERE shipped = '0' GROUP by serial_number"
```

This just gives me the max revision for that serial number but returns all data from the first entry and not the last revision entry.

My database has hundreds of entries and I want to populate a datagridview with all the entries grouped by serial number, but only show the serial number entry with the highest revision.  I hope this makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, but maybe with this :

```
SELECT reference as ""Reference"", serial_number as ""Serial Number"", revision as ""Revision"", Model as ""Model"" 
FROM configurator.final_order 
WHERE revision = MAX(revision) AND shipped = '0' 
GROUP by serial_number
```

Comment: I received an error with the above statement.  Said "invalid use of group function"                                                          I am wanting to show all results that have not been shipped, but with that there could be duplicate entries that have the same machine serial number.  The difference between the duplicate entries would be revision number.  I only want to pull the entries with the highest revision number for every machine serial number.  Hope this helps to explain what i am trying to do.

Comment: My bad, just add all fields in the select clause in the group by as follow : `GROUP by reference, revision, serial_number, Model`